# open detail view with request parameter

Tags: jsf, richfaces, myfaces

I created a simple master/detail using myfaces and richfaces. By clicking a h:commandLink in the rich:dataTable the user is able to open the detail view and edit the entity.

Now I want to create a URL that allows the user to open the detail view directly. Normally I would to this by creating an URL like /detail.jsp?id=12 - how can I achieve that with JSF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the URL using parameters on a link control:

```
    <h:outputLink value="reqscope.faces">
        <f:param name="id" value="#{row.id}" />
        <h:outputText value="link" />
    </h:outputLink>
```

On the target page, you can read the id from the parameter map, either directly using the expression language or via a managed bean.

View:

```
<f:view>
    id= <h:outputText value="#{param['id']}" />
    <br />
    id= <h:outputText value="#{lookupBean.id}" />
</f:view>
```

Bean:

```
public class LookupBean implements Serializable {

    public String getId() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext extContext = context.getExternalContext();
        Map<String, String> params = extContext.getRequestParameterMap();
        return params.get("id");
    }

}
```

faces-config.xml declaration:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>lookupBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>reqscope.LookupBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use an a4j:commandlink to first pass the id of the entity I want to show details for to the detail view bean. And then I simply use document.location to navigate to the view.

```
<a4j:commandLink action="#{detailviewBean.setDetailID(entity.someid)}" value="#{entity.someid}" oncomplete="document.location='/app/detailview.seam'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSF 1.2, you can use f:setPropertyActionListener:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{reqscope.faces}">
    <h:outputText value="link"/>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener 
        value="#{id}" 
        target="#{lookupBean.id}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

[Executing Methods From LinkButton Parameters](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/ExecutingMethodsFromLinkButtonParameters)